# CSS on hover change colours of elements inside box

Tags: html, css, svg

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>

    .box {
     height: 200px;
     width: 200px;
     border: 1px solid #eee;
    }
    
    .icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 80px;
       fill: black;
    }
    
    .test-title {
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 22px;
    }
    
    .box:hover {
     
    }
     
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="box">
  <p class="test-title">Undo Icon</p>
  <svg  viewBox="0 0 32 32" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" class="icon">
   <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="test.svg#icon-undo"></use>
  </svg>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

above code gives following output

[image: plain output]

but I want following output on hover of `.box` class

[image]

I can change colour of font by doing `.test-title:hover { colour:red; }` and for svg image I can colour by using `.icon:hover { fill:red }`, but I want change colour of both image and text on hover of `.box`,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try using the child CSS selector (`>`) to do this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>

    .box {
     height: 200px;
     width: 200px;
     border: 1px solid #eee;
    }
    
    .icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 80px;
       fill: black;
    }
    
    .test-title {
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 22px;
    }
    
    .box:hover, .box:hover > .icon {
     color: red;
      fill: red;
    }
     
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="box">
  <p class="test-title">Undo Icon</p>
  <svg  viewBox="0 0 32 32" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" class="icon">
   <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://139.59.35.115/test.svg#icon-undo"></use>
  </svg>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note:** Check out the last CSS rule in the example to see how this works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks @HudsonTaylor, it is working as I needed, but you forgot add `fill:red`

Comment: Whoops, just noticed that! Sorry. Would you mind marking the answer as correct? I fixed the error :)

Comment: asking me to wait for 5 minutes

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your project!